# ARC Semantic Issue: No visible @interface for 'UIStoryboard' declares selector

Tags: ios, objective-c, uistoryboard

The error I'm getting is:

> 'No visible @interface for 'UIStoryboard' declares selector
>   instantiateInitialViewControllerWithIdentifier:'

Thanks for the help.

```
#import "initViewController.h"
#import "ECSlidingViewController.h"
#import "MenuViewController.h"

@interface initViewController ()

@end

@implementation initViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.topViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateInitialViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Main"];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Comment: You should rename this class from `initViewController` (which looks like a method name) to something like `InitialViewController`. Class names should be nouns. At the moment your class name is more of a verb.

Comment: Will do. Coming from Java and I have all sorts of bad programming habits.

Comment: Funny how this is closed as "This question is unlikely to help any future visitors". This certainly helps *me* as I have the same question as the asker, and found the accepted answer very helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[UIStoryboard](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIStoryboard_Class/Reference/Reference.html) doesn't implement a method by that name.  It does implement `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:`, which looks like what you need.

Answer (score 0):

(1) add `#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>` to the top of the file & make sure you spelled the method exactly correctly.

(2) Class names should be capitalized.